# inverting op amp with a load resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier

what is the impact of a resistor when it is connected to the output terminal of an inverting amplifier. Does it make any difference to the output voltage or to the gain?

Comment: If the resistor is outside of the feedback loop then No, not really, it'll just drop some of the voltage depending on the load (V=IR so more I means more V's of drop). If said resistor is *inside* the feedback loop, well things can get complicated as the load can now affect the feedback path.

Comment: it is outside the loop. so the gain doesnt change?

Comment: Yep, the gain is set inside the loop. Putting a heavy load on the output will cause you to lose some of your signal across the output resistor but this is more like output sag than a gain change.

Comment: @Tom, your first comment is not quite correct. The feedback loop will maintain voltage at the output (unless the load exceeds the capability of the opamp). That's the whole idea of the feedback - to adjust the amplifier output until the output is input \$\times\$ gain. It _would_ drop voltage if it was in series between the output and the load being driven but I don't think that's what's being asked.

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where you can put your resistor.
Outside the feedback loop and Inside the feedback loop.

If you place it outside the feedback loop(other terminal of the resistance is not connected to any terminal of the feedback resistance),then it became a part of your load, not the op-amp circuit.So it do not effect your gain.But it will effect your load resistance.

If you place it inside the feedback circuit,then it will become a part of feedback resistance. According to the connection of the other terminal of the resistance , it may act as parallel or series resistance with main feedback resistance and gain will change .Gain will change according to the equivalent resistor of the main feedback resistance and added the new one.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make any difference to the output voltage or to the gain?

- It can restrict the peak to peak voltage swings of the op-amp - this isn't necessarily a bad thing of course and it may be intentional in some circuits.
- It can increase op-amp's power dissipation and this may be a bad thing
- It can reduce open-loop gain at high frequencies leading to some high frequency closed loop errors. This is manly seen on rail-to-rail outputs.
- Sometimes slew rates can be modified by too high an output load.

To a certain degree, any resistor load is "inside" the feedback loop due to finite (not zero) output drive resistance of the op-amp. The degree that the resistor affects the output signal depends usually on how low it's value is.